# Java Database Not Connected When Casting Result Set to Object Array

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

So I'm attempting to convert my result set into an array of objects that map the data fields however i'm getting a db connection error even though I call it to open? If I don't call the CRM.SQLServer.DisconnectDB(); it will work correctly. Apparently I need to add more details so i'm typing to add more details right now.

**Connection Error:**

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:191)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.checkClosed(SQLServerConnection.java:710)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.checkClosed(SQLServerStatement.java:1071)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.checkClosed(SQLServerResultSet.java:387)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.next(SQLServerResultSet.java:1009)
    at main.DataClasses.Companies.ConvertToArrayList(Companies.java:51)
    at main.CRM.main(CRM.java:35)
    ... 11 more
Exception running application main.CRM
```

**Main Class:**

```
package main;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import main.DataClasses.Companies;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CRM extends Application {

    public static SQLServer SQLServer = new SQLServer();
    public static Users Users = new Users();
    public static Navigation Navigation = new Navigation();
    public static Companies Companies = new Companies(); 

    public static String Verision ="0.0.1";

    @Override
    public void start (Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("UI/Login.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Basic CRM Verision:"+Verision);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600,400));
    primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        launch(args);

        ArrayList<Companies> result = Companies.ConvertToArrayList(Companies.SelectTopCompanies(10));
        for(Companies temp:result) {
            System.out.println(temp.getCompanyName());
        }

    }

}
```

**Companies Class:**

```
package main.DataClasses;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import main.CRM;

public class Companies {

 private int mID;
 private String mCompanyName;
 private String mCity;
 private int mZipCode;
 private String mState;

 public Companies() {}
 public Companies(int ID, String CompanyName, String City, int ZipCode, String State) throws SQLException {
  mID = ID;
  mCompanyName = CompanyName;
  mCity = City;
  mZipCode = ZipCode;
  mState = State;
 }
 public String getCompanyName() {
  return mCompanyName;
 }
 public void CreateCompany(String CompanyName, String City, int ZipCode, String State) throws SQLException {
  String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO Company" + "(CompanyName, City, ZipCode, State) VALUES" + "(?,?,?,?)";
  PreparedStatement preparedStatement = CRM.SQLServer.conn.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);
  preparedStatement.setString(1, CompanyName);
  preparedStatement.setString(2, City);
  preparedStatement.setInt(3, ZipCode);
  preparedStatement.setString(4, State);
  CRM.SQLServer.ConnectToDB();
  preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
  CRM.SQLServer.DisconnectDB();
 }
 public ResultSet SelectTopCompanies(int amount) throws SQLException {
  CRM.SQLServer.ConnectToDB();
  PreparedStatement statement = CRM.SQLServer.conn.prepareStatement("SELECT TOP " + amount + " * FROM Company");
  ResultSet CompanyResultSet = statement.executeQuery();
  CRM.SQLServer.DisconnectDB();
  return CompanyResultSet;

 }

 public ArrayList < Companies > ConvertToArrayList(ResultSet resultset) throws SQLException {
  CRM.SQLServer.ConnectToDB();
  ArrayList < Companies > result = new ArrayList < Companies > ();
  while (resultset.next()) {
   result.add(new Companies(resultset.getInt("ID"), resultset.getString("CompanyName"),
    resultset.getString("City"), resultset.getInt("ZipCode"), resultset.getString("State")));
  }
  CRM.SQLServer.DisconnectDB();
  return result;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's because the connection rely to your [ResultSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) is closed.

> A ResultSet object is automatically closed when the Statement object that generated it is closed, re-executed, or used to retrieve the next result from a sequence of multiple results.

You can go through your resultSet once

> A default ResultSet object is not updatable and has a cursor that moves forward only. Thus, you can iterate through it only once and only from the first row to the last row. It is possible to produce ResultSet objects that are scrollable and/or updatable. The following code fragment, in which con is a valid Connection object, illustrates how to make a result set that is scrollable and insensitive to updates by others, and that is updatable. See ResultSet fields for other options

So the simplest solution is to "merge" your methods to have this :

```
 public ArrayList < Companies > SelectTopCompanies(int amount) throws SQLException {...}
```